# ROS Kinect - Getting sensor data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to the ROS middleware framework and I do not understand how I would extract the sensor point data from the Kinect using C++?

I have been looking into using the `sensor_msgs/PoinntCloud2.h` and extracting the points that will be able to publish the data onto a new topic called "kinect_sensor" but I cannot seem to find any tutorials out there which will allow me to do this?

Hope someone can help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106841/ros-kinect---getting-sensor-data/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understood well, you simply want to publish kinect data over ROS. Then I suggest you to look at this [package](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch).
Once your Kinect is connected, simply run the command:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

it will publish a list of topic with depth image, rgb image, point cloud, info etc.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on 2013-12-04**:
@Tirjen Thanks for your reply. I have installed open_ni and want to use the topic on point cloud, this is fine. I just don't know how to  access this using C++ in a subscriber and talker scripts.. Any advice?

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-12-04**:
So you have a topic publishing a PointCloud2 message and you want to subscribe to it? If so, just subscribe to it as to any other topic.
inside your code declare a publisher a node handle and then subscribe to it:
ros::Subscriber cloudsub_=n_.subscribe("/camera/depth/points", 1, cloudcb);
where cloudcb is your callback function.